# React Hook Initializing the state with server call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Working with a react component using hooks.  I am attempting to assign values to my state after an Axios call.  The data is correctly returned and it appears the state is correctly updated; however, the DOM is not updating with the values. Is this the proper method for doing this?

```
export const Main = (props) => {
    const { token } = useParams()    
    const [user,setUser] = useState({name:""})        
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getUser = async() =>{
            const response = await API.post("usrinfo",{token:token})
            setUser({name:response.data.name});
        }
        getUser()
    },[token])
    return(
        <div className="main-header">{user.name}</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: If the state is updated, then DOM should update. Make sure that you don't get any error while making the HTTP request. Use the `try-catch` block to catch and handle any errors during the HTTP request. Also check for any errors on the console.

Comment: As @Yousaf mentioned if state updates, DOM should also update. It might be you get some errors or state is not updated as you expect to. Can you provide more details?

Comment: As stated, the information is returned to the server without error.  Not sure what other details I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

AXIOS returns a data portion in it's response so instead of `response.data.name` it should be `response.data.data.name`.

Thanks for all your responses.